# Reading next line in python in for loop

Tags: python

I want to read the next line in the file every time the for loop continues.
Here is the code

```
file1 = open('users.txt', 'r')
lines = file1.readlines()
for i in range(len(lines)):
    file1 = open('users.txt', 'r')
    lina=file1.readline()
    parts = lina.strip().split(':')
    print(parts[0])
    print(parts[1])
    continue
```

btw i = 3 because the file consists of total 3 lines!
So the output of this code is:

```
user1
user1pass
user1
userpass
user1
userpass
```

What i want is:

```
user1
user1pass
user2
user2pass
user3
user3pass
```

Comment: Dont open `users.txt` over and over again, reuse the `lines` you already have.

Answer (score 4):

As the commenter mentioned, you are opening the file and only using the first line on every iteration of the loop. You can simplify this a lot and just iterate over the lines themselves without worrying about the index

```py
with open('users.txt', 'r') as file1:
    for line in file1:
        parts = line.strip().split(':')
        print(parts[0])
        print(parts[1])
```

Comment: Since a text file is iterable you don't even need `readlines()`. This is just unnecessary overhead. Drop `lines = file1.readlines()` and change `for line in lines:` to `for line in file1:`